# Why does my click handler fail after 2 clicks?

Tags: jquery

My aim is to toggle between two images up and down.

This is what i have, and it works partially.

If this is OK then what am i missing?
When i click two times it stops working....

Here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".collapse").click(function () {
           $("#box").hide();
           $(".collapse").replaceWith('<span class="open"></span>');
           $(".open").click(function () {
               $("#box").show();
               $(".open").replaceWith('<span class="collapse"></span>');
           });
       });
   });
```

Comment: Others are providing answers which should help, but just FYI, the clicks stop working because you are replacing the elements the click events are bound to

Comment: @Neal - you can guess what's the best way without the HTML, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Neal, why did you change the main point of the question being asked?

Comment: @jfriend00 because the main point was that the click was failing after 2 clicks.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just removed **one** non-constructive line.

Comment: @Neal - you completely rewrote the title which substantially changes the question being asked to a much narrower topic.  Failing after two clicks is only one fault with the code.  It's a generally bad approach, replacing spans when just a class should be changed, etc...  Lots more to fix and being asked about than just solve the two clicks problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 then rollback (or edit it better). But the way it looked before , it was prone to being closed for being "not constructive"

Comment: @Neal - I'll propose a clean way of solving this problem only when I can see the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Instead of your `replaceWith` just do:

```
$(".open").removeClass("open").addClass("collapse");
//and
$(".collapse").removeClass("collapse").addClass("open");
```

And change the `.click` to this (using `on(...)`):

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapse", function () {
    ....
});
```

---

Putting that all together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", ".collapse, .open", function () {
       $("#box").toggle();
       $(this).toggleClass("open", "collapse"); //toggles btw the two classes
   });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure about your putting it all together part

Comment: @Huangism sorry, **now** i fixed it ^_^

Comment: not sure if i am missong something but this did not work. can you explain it, maybe that way i can see what i missed

Comment: @user618879 well what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

yor are enclosing two click events. seperate it. try below code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".collapse").click(function() {
                $("#box").hide();
                $(this).removeClass('collapse');
                        $(this).addClass('open');
            });
            $(".open").click(function() {
                $("#box").show();
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                        $(this).addClass('collapse');
            });
        });
```

Comment: this won't solve it, you are still doing the replace

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar this still won't solve it :-P

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use **Css** instead.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".collapse").toggleClass('closed')
```

**Css:**

```
.collapse { 
    background: url(image/arrow-up.jpg); 
}
.collapse.closed {
    background: url(image/arrow-down.jpg); 
}
.collapse > #box {
    display: block;
}
.collapse.closed > #box {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: How in all does this answer anything?

Comment: Why using jQuery to replace an arrow and show a div? You can acheive this with mostly Css by adding a class in jQuery and than changing the style of the childrens of this div.